# How to retrieve a docx file from SQL Server database to ASP.NET Core console application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am making a micro-application using an ASP.NET Core console application and I need to retrieve a `.docx` file from a server database.

Any examples or suggestions?

Comment: Question: Why are you downloading a docx file from a "Database" server? Is the docx file just "living" on a server that also happens to host databases on it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the new .Net Core 3.1 Windows Service template. I recently wrote 3 small services that update database tables from other data sources. One being LDAP and the other being an Excel file available on a SFTP server.

Depending on your Use Case, I would recommend either using a connection to the SQL server using the SqlConnection class, and access the document from there, or access the document using SFTP (database server or not). There are some libraries for SFTP for .Net Core and plenty of tutorials online.

In either case, you would use your preferred connection to download the file locally as some sort of data stream most likely. Once it's downloaded locally to the server you could further utilize SFTP to send the file wherever you want on the network.

Question: Why are you downloading a docx file from a "Database" server? Is the docx file just "living" on a server that also happens to host databases on it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) to read the data as a Stream and CopyTo a FileStream.  EG

```
            var fn = "Seat Assembly.doc";
            var outFile = $@"c:\\temp\\{fn}";
            using (var con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=AdventureWorks2017;Integrated Security=true"))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"
select Document
from production.document
where FileName = @fn";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fn", fn));

                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(outFile))
                {
                    if (!rdr.Read())
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"File not found {fn}");
                    }
                    rdr.GetStream(0).CopyTo(fs);
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
```